# How to install java/android package from github onto my android device?

Tags: android, github, arabic

I'm not an android developer and don't really know anything about it so forgive me if this is a silly question.  Basically, I've come across an android package that is supposed to support the correct display of Arabic letters on android devices.  Here's the link: https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

Now, all I see are two java files that I can download.  But how am I supposed to install this package?  Do I need root access to my android device?  Is there a directory that I need to put them in?  There's no tutorial or guide in the readme file.

Answer (score 1):

> But how am I supposed to install this package?

Step #1: Learn Android development.

Step #2: Create an Android application.

Step #3: Contact the author of that code to get a license for it, as it is not open source.

Step #4: Add the code to your application and use it to fix the Arabic behavior in your app. Note that this may not be needed on newer devices, and may actually have issues on newer devices, given changes in bi-di text handling.

> Do I need root access to my android device?

I doubt it.

> Is there a directory that I need to put them in?

Somewhere in the `src/` of your Android application project on your development machine.

This code is not an Android app, nor is it designed to do anything for an entire device.